# Functional form of convergent infinite geometric series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, cauchy-sequences

I am trying to determine the conditions under which the following term is an increasing, concave function of $x_t$:

$$\sum_{t=0}^\infty \delta^{t+1} \frac{x_{t+1}(x_{t})}{h_{t+1}(x_t)}A$$
where $\delta <1$; the elasticity of $x_{t+1}$ to $x_t$ is $0< \alpha <1$ (as $\ln{x_{t+1}} = u + \alpha \ln{x_t}$); and the elasticity of $h_{t+1}$ to $x_t$ is $0< \beta <1$.

I suspect this is wrong: simplify the term as $\frac{A}{1-\delta} \sum_{t=0}^\infty\frac{x_{t+1}(x_{t})}{h_{t+1}(x_t)}$. This has an elasticity (wrt $x_t$) of $\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} - \frac{\beta}{1-\alpha}$, which implies that the term is concave as long as $2\alpha - \beta < 1$.

Would be grateful to receive any pointers.

Comment: Yeah, you cannot simplify like that. A simpler example where you can easily see your method is wrong:
$$ \frac1{1-\delta x} = \sum_{t=0}^\infty \delta ^t x^t \overset{?!}{≠ }  \frac1{1-\delta} \sum_{t=0}^\infty  x^t = \frac{1}{(1-\delta)(1-x)}$$
(In addition you've missed one factor of $\delta$) When you write $x_{t+1}(x_t)$, is this like $f(x)$? as in $x_{t+1}$ is a function of $x_t$? What about $h_{t+1}$?

Comment: Thank you, Calvin. Yes that is what I meant: $X$ at time $t$ is a function of $X$ at $t-1$; and the same for $h_{t+1}$. My thinking now is that the elasticity is simply $$\frac{\alpha - \beta}{1-\delta \alpha}$$

Comment: Hm, I'm having a number of difficulties understanding the set up. If you intend to use something to write each $x_{t+1}$ as a function of $x_t$, then this goes all the way down to $x_0$; you then don't have a function of $x_t$, but a function of $x_0$. (in any case, $t$ should be a dummy variable). Also I don't understand what you would mean by the elasticity of $h_{t+1}$ to $x_t$;  the previous example of elasticity of $x_{t+1}$ doesn't seem to help me get the definition for $h_{t+1}$, unless $h_{t+1} = x_{t+1}$...? Sorry if I'm being daft